# Remove extra language

Tags: transactions, sitecore, sitecore8

Everything was fine and sudden in translation drop-down an extra language is started to appear [screen-cast](https://www.screencast.com/t/aFjRDqhbT) & in publish wizard one language (English) is no longer visible [screen-cast](https://www.screencast.com/t/H93RRaWMev) but we have only two languages under system node which is required [screen-cast](https://www.screencast.com/t/SzdaJFpQ).

Answer (score 0):

I have got a clue/reason that someone renamed language from "**ar**" to "**ar-SA**" under system/Languages node which was causing issue & renaming back resolved issue in version drop-down.
It might be helpful for anyone else in future.

but still in publish wizard it's showing only one language